# Make an ajax request to get some data, then redirect to a new page, passing the returned data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to redirect after a successful ajax request (which I know how to do) but I want to pass along the returned data which will be used to load an iframe on the page I just redirected to.

What's the best way to pass such data along and use it to open and populate an iframe in the page I just redirected to?

---

*EDIT:*
I am passing a GET variable but am having to use the following to access it for use in my iframe src attribute:

```
function $_GET(q,s) {
        s = (s) ? s : window.location.search;
        var re = new RegExp('&'+q+'=([^&]*)','i');
        return (s=s.replace(/^\?/,'&').match(re)) ? s=s[1] : s='';
    }

var d = $_GET('thedata');
```

I assume there isn't really a more straightforward way to access the GET vars?

Comment: Why don't you make a regular post back and get the values for the iframe directly from the server?

Comment: @lonesomeday - something like: 344565ghd557ddje

Comment: @Dave - How would that work differently than doing it via ajax?

Comment: @rg88: If the only intent of the ajax call is to load some data to determine, what page should be displayed in the iframe, then it'd be easier to do a regulare postback and then write the `src` of the iframe directly into the html you're returning.

Comment: @Dave - I see. Well, here is what is happening... you click a link to launches a page that displays an interactive chat type session. The ajax request gets a string that determines some data for the interactive session. So what I need to do is grab the returned string, redirect to the destination and load the correct interactive session in an iframe on that page. Does that clarify? I'm not returning any html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not too much data, you could pass it as a get parameter in the redirect:

```
document.location = "/otherpage?somevar=" + urlescape(var)
```

Remember that urls are limited to 1024 chars, and that special chars must be escaped.

If it is beyond that limit your best move is to use server side sessions.  You will use a database on the server to store the necessary information and pass a unique identifier in the url, or as a cookie on the users computer.  When the new page loads, it can then pull the information out of the database using the identifier.  Sessions are supported in virtually every web framework out of the box.

Another alternative may be to place the data as a hidden attribute in a form which uses the post method (to get around the 1024 char limit), and simulating a submission of the form in javascript to accomplish the redirect, including the data.

Comment: So I'm passing the variable like this but I also need to use the following function (actually, the function is in my edited question) to access the GET variable for use in my iframe src attribute:

Comment: If you have access to the server, then you can retrieve the GET variable there, and render the page using it, or just render a script tag with the variable initialized to the value.  Most server-side frameworks provide an easy way of getting GET variables; easier than doing it on javascript.  That being said, your function would work.